# Web3.eth.subscribe stuck

Tags: web3js, nodejs

Try to explain what my problem is, hope someone will help me with that

```
web3.eth.subscribe('newPendingTransactions', (error, result) => {

...do something

})
```

There is .subcribe in web3 (nodejs). While the code (...do something) is running, the next subscription will not work. I need to make the subscription work independently of other processes.

For example, subcribe found new tx, start working with that and in that moment found another one tx and should work with that.

Now it stuck until first subcribe code will not be finished

Comment: What do you mean by "the next subscription will not work"? In any case javascript is a single thread language.

Comment: Sure, but anothers callback works fine. They should work independently of other processes

Comment: What do you mean by "the next subscription will not work"? it explodes, does nothing, does something else. Can you share a minimal reproducible example?